# Website Usage Tracking with Colfusion/JavaScript/Other

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

Our website development team manages many web sites (each with a different vanity URL) on our INTRAnet.  We'd like to implement something (code snippet) that is easy to add the Application.cfm/OnRequestEnd.cfm page which would insert a record into the database tracking things like page, url, querystring, userid, etc - basic stuff.  Inserting the record is not a big deal.  What I'd like to know is from a performance stand point, what would you all recommend so that we dont' get a bottleneck of inserts queued up as employees hit the various sites.  We can't use jQuery since not every site will have the same version of jQuery so we really are limited to just using Coldfusion - I think.

Ideally, what we'd like to be able to do is create one main tracking file on our main server and reference that file from all of our other sites.  Then if/when we need to make an update, we can make a global change - kind of like how Google Analytics does, just not nearly as much details.

On all of the sites we support, we do have our department logo on those pages.  I thought about building a tracking process into the loading of the image, much like they do with emails.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated of if you have a better idea - I'm all ears.

**UPDATED**
Regarding the image processing, I could not find the original link for the tutorial from easycfm.com but I found what appears to be the identical code here:  http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Web_Servers/ColdFusion/A_2386-Track-your-Emails-using-coldfusion.html

Comment: Custom tag in on request end is probably your best bet.

Comment: I suggest using cfthread for the inserts.

Comment: Why the hell did someone vote to close this?!

Comment: @DanBracuk exception thrown in cfthread are swallowed by CF, so I wouldn't run it in cfthread until it's developed well, and add appropriate logging for exceptions.

Comment: It doesn't look like any of the people who closed this have any background in CFML so I don't think they have the right to close this...

Comment: That's never stopped folks before, Sean. :\

Comment: @SeanCorfield Adam brought this up a while back and it was quickly shot down - to only allow people who have experience with relevant tags to close questions.

Comment: This question is fine as it stands. I don't know why people had voted to close it (glad it's been reopened)

Comment: Thanks for the love, guys.  I was a little puzzled to for the request to have it closed.

Comment: You may also consider using GA on your Intranet if your users can access google-analytics.com site and if your Intranet is accessible through a fully qualified domain name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam Cameron's answer is probably the way you should go. On top of that what I would suggest is inserting those records into a table with no additional indexes. This will cause the inserts to be very quick. Then you can use a scheduled database job to move this data into a nice normalised schema that is quick to analyse.

I wouldn't write off using JavaScript just because each site will have a different version of JQuery. People still used to be able to get stuff done prior to the existence of JQuery it is just a JavaScript library. It is very basic JavaScript to include dynamically include a script file that points at your tracking file with the relevant parameters.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    script.setAttribute("src", "http://www.yourdomain.com/trackingfile.cfm?" + yourparams);
    body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

As you can see, no need for JQuery.

Comment: I'm learning about CFC so that implementation of Adam's solution will take me a couple of days but what I can see from teh little bit I've worked with, his approach is a good one - I just don't fully understand it yet.  With your approach, would I put this code snippet on www.domainA.com, www.domainB.com, and www.DomainC.com and then the script would all point to my centralized (or in NZ it would be centralised **wink**) server, www.maintrackingserver.com?

Comment: It is completely up to you. As you have several sites to look after it would seem easier to have one site that takes care of the tracking for you instead of print it several places. The example I gave you will work across domains so you have both options.

Comment: I selected this because it did exactly what we needed it to do and was pretty quick to implement in our development environment and the results were spot-on.  Thanks baynezy!

Answer (score 6):

I would say that you should not try to prematurely optimise this until you have a reason to. If you find you have a problem down the track, you can deal with it then.

Create a Logging CFC and implement a method which receives the metrics you wish to log, and then wraps that up into a record to insert into the DB, and use `<cfquery>` to write them to a DB table. Call the function from OnRequestEnd.cfm.

I specifically suggest rolling this into a Logging CFC because if you need to change the implementation of how you log things later on, you can just change the inner workings of the logging method, instead of having to mess with all your sites.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "prematurely optimise"  Can you elaborate?  Also, in order to use a CFC, don't you have to have Application.cfc/OnRequestEnd.cfc or is Application.cfm/OnRequestEnd.cfm okay?

Comment: OK, firstly: if you see a term you don't understand, you can simply google it. But here you go: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization. Secondly, if you don't know how some code might work, you can *try it and find out* (taking this approach will improve your capabilities as a programmer). However there is no corelation between using CFCs and using Application.cfc, no.

Comment: Wow:  I do sincerely appreciate the help you have provided and I am very familiar with googling terms but in the US, we spell "optimize" with a Z so I wasn't sure if your "optimise" meant something different so I asked for clarification, my bad.

Comment: I think on the whole if you see a word spelled "-ise" you can just assume it's a rest-of-world(*) spelling of whatever word you'd be familiar with having "-ize". And if in doubt, you can still google it with either spelling ;-)  (*) Except perhaps Australia... I think they use en-US spelling there too (I'm in NZ, so we use en-GB).